# В проверке имени выскакивает null вместо "не указано". Как это исправить?

Tags: javascript

Почему-то в проверке имени выскакивает null вместо "не указано". Как это исправить?

```js
          var name = prompt("Введите Ваше имя");

          do {
            if (parseFloat(name)) {
              alert("Не вводите числа в имя!"),
                (name = prompt("Введите имя еще раз"));
            }
          } while (parseFloat(name));
          if (name == null || name == undefined) {
            name = "не указано";
          }

          var surname = prompt("Введите Вашу фамилию");

          do {
            if (parseFloat(surname)) {
              alert("Не вводите числа в фамилию!"),
                (surname = prompt("Введите фамилию еще раз"));
            }
          } while (parseFloat(surname));
          if (surname == null || surname == undefined) {
            surname = "не указано";
          }

          var patronymic = prompt("Введите Ваше отчество");

          do {
            if (parseFloat(patronymic)) {
              alert("Не вводите числа в отчество!"),
                (patronymic = prompt("Введите отчество еще раз"));
            }
          } while (parseFloat(patronymic));
          if (patronymic == null || patronymic == undefined) {
            patronymic = "не указано";
          }

          var adult = "";
          var pension = "";

          var gender = confirm("Вы мужчина??");
          if (gender) {
            var gender = "мужской";
          } else {
            gender = "женский";
          }

          var ageYear = prompt("Введите Ваш возраст ( в годах)");
          ageYear = parseInt(ageYear);

          if (isNaN(ageYear)) {
            alert("Вы неправильно ввели ваш возраст!"),
              (ageYear = prompt("Введите Ваш возраст еще раз (в годах)"));
          }

          do {
            if (ageYear > 150) {
              alert("Введено слишком большое значение возраста!"),
                (ageYear = prompt("Введите Ваш возраст еще раз (в годах)"));
            } else if (ageYear < 3 && ageYear >= 0) {
              alert("Введено слишком маленькое значение возраста!"),
                (ageYear = prompt("Введите Ваш возраст еще раз (в годах)"));
            } else if (ageYear < 0) {
              alert("Введено отрицательное значение возраста!"),
                (ageYear = prompt("Введите Ваш возраст еще раз (в годах)"));
            }
          } while (ageYear > 150 || ageYear < 3);

          if (ageYear > 18 && ageYear >= 60) {
            adult = "Вы уже совершеннолетний(ая)";
            pension = "да";
          } else if (ageYear > 18 && ageYear < 60) {
            adult = "Вы уже совершеннолетний(ая)";
            pension = "нет";
          } else if (ageYear == 18) {
            adult = "Вам 18 лет";
            pension = "нет";
          } else if (ageYear < 18) {
            adult = "Вы еще несовершеннолетний(ая)";
            pension = "нет";
          }

          var ageDays = ageYear * 365;
          ageDays = parseFloat(ageDays);

          if (isNaN(ageDays)) {
            pension = "неизвестно";
          }

          var result =
            "Ваше ФИО: " +
            " " +
            surname +
            " " +
            name +
            " " +
            patronymic +
            "\n" +
            "Ваш возраст в годах: " +
            ageYear +
            "\n" +
            "Ваш возраст в днях: " +
            ageDays +
            "\n" +
            adult +
            "\n" +
            "Ваш пол: " +
            gender +
            "\n" +
            "Вы на пенсии: " +
            pension;

          alert(result);
```

Comment: * prompt никогда не возвращает undefined, есть смысл сравнивать только с null. А еще... `console.log( !!parseFloat("0") ); // false` - если введут ноль, if не сработает. Числа можно исключить через `if ( !isNaN( name ) )`

Answer (score 3):

Это довольно хитрый баг. Когда вы пишете `var name = prompt("Введите Ваше имя");`, вы не создаёте новую переменную, а используете свойство [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name), которое всегда уже есть перед запуском любого скрипта в контексте браузера. Ведь `var` работает с переменными как со свойствами глобального объекта.

Когда мы присваиваем какое-то значение свойству `window.name`, оно автоматически конвертируется в строку. Так `null` становится `"null"`, ваши проверки больше не работают, и эта строка потом выводится в качестве имени.

Переименуйте переменную, а лучше используйте `let` или `const`.

Comment: О_о однако, писец!) И правда: `var name = 5; console.log(typeof name); // string`

Comment: что это за запись, я не понимаю, почему js не ругается `alert("Не вводите числа в имя!"), (name = prompt("Введите имя еще раз"))`?

Comment: @МихаилКамахин "Оператор запятая". Использован не к месту)

Answer (score 1):

Если вы свой код положите в функцию, то переменые, которые вы объявляете станут локальными для этой функции и не будут доступны в глобальной области видимости. И это будет работать

```js
function myCode() {
  var name = prompt("Введите Ваше имя");

  do {
    if (parseFloat(name)) {
      alert("Не вводите числа в имя!"),
        (name = prompt("Введите имя еще раз"));
    }
  } while (parseFloat(name));
  if (name == null || name == undefined) {
    name = "не указано";
  }

  var surname = prompt("Введите Вашу фамилию");

  do {
    if (parseFloat(surname)) {
      alert("Не вводите числа в фамилию!"),
        (surname = prompt("Введите фамилию еще раз"));
    }
  } while (parseFloat(surname));
  if (surname == null || surname == undefined) {
    surname = "не указано";
  }

  var patronymic = prompt("Введите Ваше отчество");

  do {
    if (parseFloat(patronymic)) {
      alert("Не вводите числа в отчество!"),
        (patronymic = prompt("Введите отчество еще раз"));
    }
  } while (parseFloat(patronymic));
  if (patronymic == null || patronymic == undefined) {
    patronymic = "не указано";
  }

  var adult = "";
  var pension = "";

  var gender = confirm("Вы мужчина??");
  if (gender) {
    var gender = "мужской";
  } else {
    gender = "женский";
  }

  var ageYear = prompt("Введите Ваш возраст ( в годах)");
  ageYear = parseInt(ageYear);

  if (isNaN(ageYear)) {
    alert("Вы неправильно ввели ваш возраст!"),
      (ageYear = prompt("Введите Ваш возраст еще раз (в годах)"));
  }

  do {
    if (ageYear > 150) {
      alert("Введено слишком большое значение возраста!"),
        (ageYear = prompt("Введите Ваш возраст еще раз (в годах)"));
    } else if (ageYear < 3 && ageYear >= 0) {
      alert("Введено слишком маленькое значение возраста!"),
        (ageYear = prompt("Введите Ваш возраст еще раз (в годах)"));
    } else if (ageYear < 0) {
      alert("Введено отрицательное значение возраста!"),
        (ageYear = prompt("Введите Ваш возраст еще раз (в годах)"));
    }
  } while (ageYear > 150 || ageYear < 3);

  if (ageYear > 18 && ageYear >= 60) {
    adult = "Вы уже совершеннолетний(ая)";
    pension = "да";
  } else if (ageYear > 18 && ageYear < 60) {
    adult = "Вы уже совершеннолетний(ая)";
    pension = "нет";
  } else if (ageYear == 18) {
    adult = "Вам 18 лет";
    pension = "нет";
  } else if (ageYear < 18) {
    adult = "Вы еще несовершеннолетний(ая)";
    pension = "нет";
  }

  var ageDays = ageYear * 365;
  ageDays = parseFloat(ageDays);

  if (isNaN(ageDays)) {
    pension = "неизвестно";
  }

  var result =
    "Ваше ФИО: " +
    " " +
    surname +
    " " +
    name +
    " " +
    patronymic +
    "\n" +
    "Ваш возраст в годах: " +
    ageYear +
    "\n" +
    "Ваш возраст в днях: " +
    ageDays +
    "\n" +
    adult +
    "\n" +
    "Ваш пол: " +
    gender +
    "\n" +
    "Вы на пенсии: " +
    pension;
  alert(result);
}

myCode();
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю вы ввели null или отмена как указано в ответе ниже и ожидали получить "не указано" попробуйте сделать так тогда

```js
          var name = prompt("Введите Ваше имя");

          do {
            if (parseFloat(name)) {
              alert("Не вводите числа в имя!"),
                (name = prompt("Введите имя еще раз"));
            }
          } while (parseFloat(name));
          
          if (name == null || name == undefined || name == '' || name == 'null') {
            name = "не указано";
          }

          var result =
            "Ваше имя: " +
            " " +
            name;

          alert(result);
```

Comment: Не обязательно вводить  `"null"`. Поведение исходного примера можно проверить дебаггером: если нажать отмену или ESC в первом prompt, глобальной переменной `name` присваивается строка `"null"`. Объяснение в моём ответе)

Comment: да добавил описания